# How to output the whole json after making change by jq

Tags: jq

I have json file test.json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "content": "apple"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "content": "pears"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change "content" of "id"==100 to "watermelon" then output the whole of test.json.

But when I do:

```
$ jq '.data[]|select(.id==100)|.content|="watermelon"' test.json
{
  "id": 100,
  "content": "watermelon"
}
```

I don't get the output of the changed whole test.json but just the portion of it.

How do I make the aforementioned change to test.json and output the whole of test.json?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by:

```
$ jq '(.data[]|select(.id==100)).content|="watermelon"' test.json 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "content": "apple"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "content": "watermelon"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A less elegant attempt

```bash
jq '.data |= map(.content = if .id == 100 then "watermelons" else .content end)' file.json
```